# SSD performance falls off a cliff

Tags: ssd, performance, windows-11, m.2

I have a Samsung MZVLQ1T0HALB 1TB M.2 SSD which came pre-installed with my laptop, the [MSI GP66 Leopard 11UG-018](https://www.newegg.com/core-black-msi-gp-series-gp66-leopard-11ug-018-gaming-entertainment/p/N82E16834155855?Item=N82E16834155855).

When copying a 6 GB Windows ISO from My Documents to the Desktop it goes from about 1.2 GB/s to 200 MB/s.

[image]

[image]

I do not recall seeing such a disparity in my 2.5" SATA III SSDs over the past 10 years.

Overall, I'm satisfied with the SSD performance but in the future I do have plans to upgrade to a 4TB drive.

Can I expect a similar bottleneck?

Should I be worried about the current performance issue?

---

Per comment request.

Performance of extracting the ISO into a folder and then copying that folder to the desktop.

[image]

Comment: It's normal behaviour because the ISO file is just an archive file that still contains thousands of files within it. The speed will drop once your machine starts processing thousands of individual files.

Comment: You can test this theory by finding a 6GB MOV file and copying that to your SSD. For a single file like that you should find it stays steady at high speed.

Comment: @Mastaxx I'm not sure I follow. Why doesn't the operating system treat it as one large file?

Comment: @Mastaxx I added a screenshot of what your theory suggests and it behaves much more erratically as expected.

Comment: I don't know. There's just so many variables involved that could affect it. The format of your SSD (ExFat is terrible at small files), the amount of files inside the ZIP file, the CPU power (processing of small files). As to why i'm not sure, but as i say you can test the theory by copying a 6GB MOV to your SSD and observe the expected performance. This should re-assure you that your SSD is in good health.

Comment: @Mastaxx I'll have to find a MOV file then; maybe I'll call 1998 and see if I can borrow one lol

Comment: Try a test file https://fastest.fish/test-files

Comment: The main thing here is you're extracting thousands of files, so this doesn't only involve your SSD. It's also requiring CPU to process it all.

Comment: @Mastaxx At least one of us didn't read the question at hand.

Comment: @Mastaxx I entertained your theory and a 5 GB file from that website behaved exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

**TL;DR**

You get what you pay for.

---

The Samsung MZVLQ1T0HALB is a bottom-of-the-barrel SSD.

I bought a SAMSUNG 980 PRO M.2 2280 1TB and now the same operation gets 1.5 GB/s consistently.

Answer (score 6):

This question comes up again and again : The disk is not slowing down,
it runs at the same speed all the time.

What you're seeing is at first Windows filling up the computer's memory
with data, relatively fast because it's mostly only reading data into
memory.

Once memory is full, you need to write out data in order to read in
some more, so then you operate at the writing speed of the SSD.

Evidently, your SSD can read relatively fast, but is slow on write.

For your next SSD, before buying, study well the performance figures
given by the manufacturer and compare them with technical reviews
of the disk (they're not always the same).
A faster (and costlier) disk will give better results.

Comment: So that window aggregates the read and write speed? That is news to me. I'll have to figure out a way to profile the SSD and compare it against what the Windows dialogue shows.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - Don't bother trying to profile the dialogue.  There is a ex-Microsoft employee, who as the individual who programmed this particular feature, let's just say that Windows tells little white lies within that dialog.  With regards to copying a file from one location to another locate on an SSD. Some performance his would be expected since the drive is both reading and writing.  I am not exactly sure I agree with the comments that Windows treats an ISO files as multiple compressed files, that certainly is NOT how it handles zip files.

Comment: @Ramhound: I agree that the multiple files comment is incorrect. A file is a file, even a Zip file.

Comment: From what I understand, in addition to a RAM buffer SSDs can use a small portion of the TLC (or QLC, and so on) as if it was SLC for increased speed, and then at some time in the future save the data to TLC. Once that buffer is used up, it is down to its native multi-level cell writing speed.

Comment: @Ramhound you watch Dave's videos too? :)

Comment: Oh, the programmer I was talking about, is on YouTube.  I guess my comment is out of the blue with that fact.  They did a video on the copy file dialog.

Comment: @Ramhound I was talking about David Plummer, or YT channel Dave's Garage, ex microsoft engineer

Comment: @LPChip - Dito..Would have worked at Microsoft if I was born in 1972 instead of 1982

Comment: @Ramhound even though I'm only one year older than you, not from America either, so that would have made things a lot more complicated.

Comment: @Ramhound I ran the same test with HWMonitor open and it reports 700 MB/s peak for both read and write. I'll see if I can log the performance using that software or maybe Windows resource monitor has something 

Comment: @harrymc Do you have a source for this? "What you're seeing is at first Windows filling up the computer's memory with data, relatively fast because it's mostly only reading data into memory."